# Adding E-Commerce to a Jekyll site

Tags: web, e-commerce, jekyll

How can I add a shop page to my site built with jekyll and foundation?

Any automated platform/way to do this will be fine.

Thanks.

Comment: Well, Jekyll is a _static_ websites generator: strangely, it means it can only build static websites.

Comment: Thanks :( I guess I will look for another platform.

Comment: @Sylvain "static" has no bearing on whether you can do ecommerce with Jekyll. Do in in Javascript. Store you products on the filesystem..

Answer (score 5):

You could use [snipcart](http://www.snipcart.com). There is a [blog post](https://snipcart.com/blog/static-site-e-commerce-part-2-integrating-snipcart-with-jekyll) and a [demo site](http://snipcart.github.io/snipcart-jekyll-integration/) that will get you up an running.

There is also [Jekyll-store](http://www.jekyll-store.com/) that has the benefit of keeping all the data stored on the webpage, and, unlike snipcart, is free.

Comment: seems like the jekyll-store project has been abandoned... https://bradonomics.github.io/jekyll-cart/ might work as an alternative

Answer (score 2):

Maybe use PayPal's buy now buttons (https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_singleitem-intro-outside) or some other simple purchase system's button. Maybe Strip has some good options too.

Once you get to needing a real cart. You should just use a real application first and simple content management second.

Answer (score 1):

[EvilText](http://eviltext.com) (open source static site generator similar to Jekyll) have eCommerce plugin, see [sample shop](http://shop-example.eviltext.com).